# Tips for solving a Linear Differential Equation with Laplace

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I'm trying to solve the following differential equation:

$y''(t)+3y'(t)+2y(t) = f(t)$ , where $f(t) =(t, 0 <= t <= 1), (0, 1< t) $ with initial condition being $y(0)=0=y'(0)$.

Applying the Laplace Transform to both sides I obtain

$F(p) = (1-e^(-p))/(p^2(p+1)(p+2))$ with $Re(p)>0$.

How should I continue?

Comment: So here $F(p) $ is the Laplace transformation of $y$ ?

Comment: I get $(1-pe^{-p}-e^{-p})$ on the top line. Write $\frac{1}{p^2(p+1)(p+2)}$ in terms of partial fractions, multiply out the several terms then use the shift result $f(t-1)u(t-1)$ has transform $e^{-p}F(p)$ to invert, where u(t) is the Heaviside step function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the [partial fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) of $$\frac{1}{t^2\left(t+1\right)\left(t+2\right)}=\frac{1}{2t^2}+\frac{1}{t+1}-\frac{1}{4\left(t+2\right)}-\frac{3}{4t}.$$ 
\begin{align*}
\mathscr{L}(y)= & \frac{1-e^{-t}}{2t^2}+\frac{1-e^{-t}}{t+1}-\frac{1-e^{-t}}{4\left(t+2\right)}-\frac{3(1-e^{-t})}{4t}\\
\implies y= & \mathscr{L}^{-1}\left( \frac{1-e^{-t}}{2t^2}+\frac{1-e^{-t}}{t+1}-\frac{1-e^{-t}}{4\left(t+2\right)}-\frac{3(1-e^{-t})}{4t} \right)
\end{align*}
Now use the [Heaviside function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) for get the inverse. 
$$ \mathscr{L}^{-1}\left( \frac{e^{-t}}{t^2} \right)=\text{H}\left(t-1\right)\left(t-1\right) $$ 
So, $$ \mathscr{L}^{-1}\left( \frac{1-e^{-t}}{2t^2} \right)=\frac{t}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\text{H}\left(t-1\right)\left(t-1\right) $$
Similarly, the remaining can be computed.

Comment: I see... but I don't understand why should the antitransform of $(e^(-t))/t^2$ be $H(t-1)(t-1)$ instead of $t-1$

Comment: This theorem you can see in any text, "Second shifting theorem." For example https://17calculus.com/laplace-transforms/shifting-theorems/

Comment: If $\mathscr{L}^{-1}(F(s))= f\left(t\right)$ then $\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left( e^{-as} F(s) \right)=H(t-a)f(t-a)$

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I'm really greatful!

Comment: You should accept the answer.